# Pass parameter from application to custom B2C policy claim

Tags: blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a Timer, that manages Blazor application session time. After it expires, application redirects me to login page.
The login page is implemented via B2C custom policies and as far as I know it is configurable with claims.

Is it possible to somehow pass a parameter from application to claim in order to then customize UI of the login page?

I am using MsalAuthentication for authentication in my app.